# Can I use .click to target only one result in a query that returns multiple results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code block returns multiple results, which are then shown to the user on the page. At the moment when the user clicks on any of the button here

```
wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="btn btn-danger mrs decline">' + 'Unfriend' + '</div>');
```

Instead of just declining one object, all objects are declined. Which is not what I want.

To make this function correctly, would it be correct to be looking to something like the following instead?

```
        $('.decline).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

--

```
mainQuery.find({
            success: function(results) {
                var friends = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    friends.push({
                        imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                        username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                        userId: results[i].get('toUser').id,
                        status: results[i].get('status'),



                        // Saves the object so that it can be used below to change the status//
                        fetchedObject: results[i]


                    });


                }
                var select = document.getElementById("FriendsConnected");
                $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                    var opt = v.username;
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                })


                $('#containerFriends').empty();
                $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();

                _.each(friends, function(item) {
                    var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
                    wrapper.append('<img class="responsive-image friendImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />' + '<br>');
                    wrapper.append('<div class="tag">' + item.username + '</div>');
                    wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="btn btn-danger mrs decline">' + 'Unfriend' + '</div>');

                    $('#containerFriends').append(wrapper);
                    //The following lets the user accept or decline a friend request by changing the status the status from Pending to Declined/////
                    $(document).on('click', function() {
//Note 1////
                        $(".decline").click(function() {
                            item.fetchedObject.set("status", "Rejected");


                            item.fetchedObject.save(null, {
                                success: function(results) {
                                    console.log("REJECTED");

                                },
                                error: function(contact, error) {
                                    // The save failed.
                                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                                }
                            });


                        });
```

Comment: This is what we call "too localized", the click handler on the "decline" button calls `item.fetchedObject.set("status", "Rejected");`, and we have no idea what `item` is, or it's properties, or the the `set()` function ?

Comment: @adeneo `item` is the iteration variable of `_.each(friends, ...)`. The loop at the top of the `success:` function fills in the `friends` array.

Comment: You shouldn't define one click handler inside another click handler. Why are you adding another `.decline` click handler every time the user clicks on the document?

Comment: @Barmar - Good eyes, following it back I see how the `friends`  array is built now, it's still not very easy to follow, and why suddenly use Underscore ?

Comment: @Barmar so basically I can remove the $(document).on('click', function() { handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the handler just to the specific element, not all `.decline` elements. Remove the `$(document).on('click', ...)` handler, and change it to:

```
wrapper.children('.decline').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code here `$('.decline).css('cursor', 'pointer');` you should add an `'` after the name of the class so it should look like this `$('.decline').css('cursor', 'pointer');`

Comment: This is obviously just a typo in the SO copy, otherwise the code wouldn't run at all.